# Finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ inside the free product $\Bbb{Z}_{2}*\Bbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

Let $\Bbb{Z_{2}*Z_{2}}$ be the free product then I want to prove that there is a finite indexed subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$.

**My attempt**:

We denote the free product  by $\langle a\rangle*\langle b\rangle$ for more clarity such that $a^{2}=e$ and $b^{2}=e$.

Then the subgroup $H=\langle ab\rangle $  is a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$. Now as for the index I think it has index $2$ as the cosets are $\{H,bH\}$.

Am I correct in thinking this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every element $g$ in your group has a well defined length modulo $2$. Namely, when $g$ is written as a word in $a$ and $b$, the number of occurences of $a$’s and $b$’s (combined) can either be even or odd, but not both. Then the mapping $\mathbb{Z}_2* \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ which sends elements of even length to $0$ and elements of odd length to $1$ is a homomorphism. The kernel of this homomorphism is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (it coincides with your $H$).

Comment: Great answer!!. It does away with dealing with generators. But still can you please tell me if my conclusion(s) were correct?

Comment: They were indeed. The only part of where you probably want to argue more is why the cosets you gave are distinct and why they they exhaust all cosets.

Comment: Nice. Correct me, if I'm wrong, but I think we can also think of this group as symmetries of the number line. With $a$ acting as the reflection $a(x)=-x$ with respect to the point $x=0$ and $b$ as the reflection $b(x)=2-x$ with respect to the point $x=1$. The group then consists of all the motions $x\mapsto\pm x+n$ with $n$ even. The subgroup you describe consists then of translations $x\mapsto x+n$.

Answer (score 4):

Your conclusion is correct.

Indeed, it checks out in GAP:

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup(2);
<free group on the generators [f1, f2] >
gap> rels:=[(F.1)^2, (F.2)^2];
[ f1^2, f2^2 ]
gap> G:=F/rels;
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> H:=Subgroup(G, [(G.1)*(G.2)]);
Group([ f1*f2 ])
gap> Index(G, H);
2
```

The first command defines the free group `F` on two elements.

The second command defines a set `rels` of relators, which the third command uses to define `G`, which is the quotient of `F` by the subgroup generated by `rels`.

The fourth command defines `H` as the subgroup of `G` generated by the set `[ (G.1)*(G.2) ]`, which corresponds to your $H$.

The final command checks the index of `H` in `G`.

Comment: I am sorry @Shaun but I don't know GAP ( I only know some SAGE) . Can you please tell me if my conclusion(s) were correct?.

Comment: I have added some explanation, @Dovahkiin.

Comment: Thanks Shaun!!(+1)

Comment: You're welcome, @Dovahkiin, and thank you for the (+1).